# Combine multiple strings into one string in Java

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I have a set of Strings that I want to combine into one String with all sentences separated with a coma (",") like in a .csv file.

Here is my code:

```
String dataContainer;

for (String tempString : setInput) {
    String finalString = "," + tempString + ",";   
}
```

This doesn't work with me :(

But it should do for `Set` e.g.:

```
Set<String> setInput = new TreeSet();
setInput.add("Dog");
setInput.add("Cat");
setInput.add("Mouse");
```

to produce the String:

```
,Dog,,Cat,,Mouse,
```

Comment: You really want 2 commas?

Comment: what do you mean by: _This doesn't work for me_

Comment: Given your inputs, how do you expect those extra commas to appear?

Answer (score 17):

It is better to use `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(String tempString:setInput){
    sb.append(",").append(tempString).append(",");   
}
```

Comment: or even `sb.append(",").append(tempString).append(",");`

Comment: @Pshemo yes, it is better. I added your suggestion.

Comment: +1 you can delete last inserted comma using `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));` if it is not necessary

Comment: code for removing of last delimiter (comma in this case) doesn't looks kind of old school, I would suggest StringJoiner or StringJoiner through java streams as I mentioned in the answer below. That has nice aesthetics :)

Comment: @Rituraj it is up to you to decide. if you are going for Java 8 yes. you can. This question originally posted even before Java 8.

Comment: Yeah. I know it was an old question, I just tried to provide a context, in case someone is using later versions of java. For prior versions I generally preferred Guava from google

Answer (score 8):

Or we can use Java 8 Stream

```
String joined = Stream.of("A", "B", "C").collect(Collectors.joining("delimiter", "prefix", "suffix"));
```

Or use the StringJoiner class

```
Directly Use StringJoiner class
```

Or the StringBuilder class

```
new StringBuilder().add("A").add("B").toString()
```

Answer (score 6):

What You are doing is  `intializing` your result string  each time.

Actually ,you want to do

```
String finalString ="";
for(String tempString:setInput){
      finalString += "," + tempString + "," ;   
}
```

But the above approach causes multiple `String` creations.

But I suggest to go for `StringBuilder`.

```
 StringBuilder finalStringb =new StringBuilder();
    for(String tempString:setInput){
          finalStringb.append(",").append(tempString).append(",") ;   
    }

String finalS = finalStringb.toString();
```

Comment: `String finalS = finalStringb.toString()` really helps me!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking only for

`String csvString = "," + String.join(",,", string1, string2, string3) +"," ;`

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Comment: Won't match the desired output of `,Dog,,Cat,,Mouse,`.

Comment: Okay so `String csvString = "," + String.join(",,", string1, string2, string3) +"," ;`

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1: (If you don't need a delimiter)**

---

I would recommend using `concat(Object... objects)` from `org.assertj.core.util.String`.

```
public static String concat(Object... objects) {
    return Arrays.isNullOrEmpty(objects) ? null : (String)java.util.Arrays.stream(objects).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
  concat("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4");
```

**Solution 2 using StringJoiner (Java 8+):**

---

This is from `java.util`. You even have the option to specify a prefix and suffix.

```
StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
 
stringJoiner.add("string1");
stringJoiner.add("string2");
stringJoiner.add("string3");
 
assertEquals("string1, string2, string3", stringJoiner.toString());
```

**Solution 3 using Collectors.joining (Java 8+):**

---

This is a functionality from Java 8 Stream API.

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("string1", "string2", "string3");
 
String concatString = stringList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
 
assertEquals("string1, string2, string3", concatString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you are using Java 8, you could try something like this:

```
public static String join(final Set<String> set){
    return new StringBuilder(",").append(set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",,"))).append(",").toString();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Set<String> setInput = new TreeSet<>();
    setInput.add("Dog");
    setInput.add("Cat");
    setInput.add("Mouse");
    System.out.println(join(setInput));
}
```

The output is:

`,Cat,,Dog,,Mouse,`

Although, I'm a little unsure to why you would want 2 commas in between each element and a comma at the start and end. If you just want one comma separating each element (and no comma at the start or end), modify the `join(Set<String>)` to look like this:

```
public static String join(final Set<String> set){
    return set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")); //change "," to ", " for spacing
}
```

After doing so, the new output would be:

`Cat,Dog,Mouse`

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join() can come in handy